# Create a dynamic 2D numpy array on the fly

Tags: python, numpy

I am having a hard time creating a `numpy` 2D array on the fly.

So basically I have a for loop something like this.

```
for ele in huge_list_of_lists:
   instance = np.array(ele)
```

creates a 1D numpy array of this list and now I want to append it to a numpy array so basically converting list of lists to array of arrays?

I have checked the manual.. and `np.append()` methods that doesn't work as for `np.append()` to work, it needs two arguments to append it together.

Any clues?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create the 2D array up front, and fill the rows while looping:

```
my_array = numpy.empty((len(huge_list_of_lists), row_length))
for i, x in enumerate(huge_list_of_lists):
    my_array[i] = create_row(x)
```

where `create_row()` returns a list or 1D NumPy array of length `row_length`.

Depending on what `create_row()` does, there might be even better approaches that avoid the Python loop altogether.

Answer (score 4):

Just pass the list of lists to `numpy.array`, keep in mind that numpy arrays are `ndarrays`, so the concept to a list of lists doesn't translate to arrays of arrays it translates to a 2d array.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = [[1., 2., 3.], [4., 5., 6.]]
>>> b = np.array(a)
>>> b
array([[ 1.,  2.,  3.],
       [ 4.,  5.,  6.]])
>>> b.shape
(2, 3)
```

Also ndarrays have nd-indexing so `[1][1]` becomes `[1, 1]` in numpy:

```
>>> a[1][1]
5.0
>>> b[1, 1]
5.0
```

Did I misunderstand your question?

You defiantly don't want to use `numpy.append` for something like this. Keep in mind that numpy.append has O(n) run time so if you call it n times, once for each row of your array, you end up with a O(n^2) algorithm. If you need to create the array before you know what all the content is going to be, but you know the final size, it's best to create an array using `numpy.zeros(shape, dtype)` and fill it in later. Similar to Sven's answer.

Answer (score 3):

`import numpy as np`

`ss = np.ndarray(shape=(3,3), dtype=int);`

```
array([[              0, 139911262763080, 139911320845424],
   [       10771584,        10771584, 139911271110728],
   [139911320994680, 139911206874808,              80]]) #random
```

numpy.ndarray function achieves this. [numpy.ndarray](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.html)